# max size of integer reached...how to covert to string that is readable (php)

Tags: php, integer

I have to send a value in microseconds. I am doing `time() * 1000` which works fine on 64 bit machines, but not on 32 bit machines. (It becomes a float).

I need to send a request in microseconds in an xml feed...what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to string and concatenate three zeroes :-)

```
echo time() . '000';
```

Answer (score 2):

For large number calculation you should use the `bcmath` functions. In your concrete case it is the `bcmul()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php

Answer (score 0):

Just append `000` to the end of the timestamp as a string

```
$microseconds = time().'000';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 str_val( time() * 1000);

 or

 sprintf('%s',time() * 1000);

 or

 time().'000';
```

Comment: The question says that `time() * 1000` is not suitable and asks for work-arounds. Your answer recommends using `time() * 1000`. This is not helpful.